# Using properties of modulus to prove an inequality

Tags: complex-analysis

> Use established properties of modulus to show that when $|z_3| \neq |z_4|$ that
>
> $$\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z_1+z_2)}{|z_3+z_4|} \leq \frac{|z_1|+|z_2|}{||z_3|-|z_4||}.$$

By the triangle inequality, we know that $|z_1+z_2| \le |z_1|+|z_2|$ from which it is easy to deduce that $\operatorname{Re}(z_1+z_2) \le |z_1+z_2|$. Another consequence is $|z_3+z_4| \ge ||z_3|-|z_4||$ and its easy to see that if $|z_3|=|z_4|$ then we have division by zero thus undefined.

It is easy to see that the inequality is valid because the left side has a larger denominator than the right side but the right side has a larger numerator. I could use some help on how to show it notationally.

Answer (score 1):

I would just write

$$\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z_1 + z_2)}{|z_3 + z_4|} \leq \frac{|z_1 + z_2|}{|z_3 + z_4|}\leq \frac{|z_1| + |z_2|}{|z_3 + z_4|} \leq \frac{|z_1| + |z_2|}{||z_3| - |z_4||}.$$

If you wanted to make the steps absolutely clear, you could write it as follows:

\begin{align*}
\frac{\operatorname{Re}(z_1 + z_2)}{|z_3 + z_4|} &\leq \frac{|z_1 + z_2|}{|z_3 + z_4|} & (\text{as}\ \operatorname{Re}(a) \leq |a|)\\
&\leq \frac{|z_1| + |z_2|}{|z_3 + z_4|} & (\text{triangle inequality})\\ 
&\leq \frac{|z_1| + |z_2|}{||z_3| - |z_4||} & (\text{as}\ |z_3 + z_4| \geq ||z_3| - |z_4||)
\end{align*}